# How can I set the max number of MySQL processes or threads?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, process

`ps axuw| grep mysql` indicates only MySQL process, but if I run htop I can see 10 rows each one of them with a separate PID. So I wonder if they are threads or processes that for some reason I cannot see using ps.

Would it make any sense to try to limit them to two on my development machine, where I don't need concurrent access of many clients.

BTW Running on Ubuntu 8.10

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can set the max number of threads in your my.ini like this:

```
max_connections=2
```

However you might also want to set this:

```
thread_cache_size=1
```

The thread cache controls how many it keeps open even when nothing is happening.

Comment: On devuan Beowulf those settings are in:

/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

Answer (score 8):

MySQL does use threads, `ps` can see them if you run `ps -eLf`.

That said, I wouldn't worry about it - dormant threads use almost no resources whatsoever, and if you constrain the server too much it's bound to come back and bite you on the backside sometime later when you've forgotten that you did it.

Answer (score 6):

There is few configuration settings in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` that would impact memory usage.

The following settings should drastically reduce the memory usage of mysql:

```
key_buffer              = 8M
max_connections         = 30
query_cache_size        = 8M
query_cache_limit       = 512K
thread_stack            = 128K
```

You can learn more here: http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/03/31/reducing-mysql-memory-usage-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/

Comment: As per the comment on the link, this change does not give any gain as quoted `Mysql consumes 21M before changes and 19M after`

Comment: Great, from 75% down to less than 50%. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was seeking for MySQL config stuff, then I saw this question.... Nothing to do with MySQL, am I right ?

If the main objective is to see the result of a custom command, you can use "watch" with the following syntax (available on most linux systems) :

```
watch "ps axuw| grep mysql"
```

It will run the command each 2 seconds and display the output, it is a very very useful command.

-> See the doc/man to see how it's powerful ;)